# When did the principal and credential injected into SecurityContextHolder

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

`SecurityContextHolder` is a convenient class that can hold static security context value. However I found when I work on customized(varies types like BASE, LDAP or just form) sometimes the principal or credential could be null. So just wondering in general what are the general class or module that user principal or credential object are injected into `SecurityContextHolder` after user is authenticated.

So that the user information can refer from

```
User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per spring documentation user credential used to store in authentication class inside SecurityContextHolder in ThreadLocal.

The underlying SecurityContextHolderStrategy used by SecurityContextHolder is, by default, an instance of ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy, which stores SecurityContexts in a ThreadLocal. Therefore, it is not necessarily a good idea to inject the SecurityContext directly into a bean at initialization time - it may need to be retrieved from the ThreadLocal each time, in a multi-threaded environment, so the correct one is retrieved.

You can put a check in your code before access the userDetails

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
    String username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
    } else {
    String username = principal.toString();
    }
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html